# Adding a Navigation Controller but navigation item not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Originally I had a custom NavigationBar, without a navigation controller. I have a sliding menu.

On the home screen there is a tableview, with a list. I would like to be able to add items to this list. So, I had to add in a navigation controller after the fact. I added the navigation controller to the storyboard and linked it to my main view controller [the one with the list]. Then I dragged in a view controller. I dropped in a bar button item into the navigation item, and pushed it to the recently added view controller.

I ran my app and the app shows no navigation bar or navigation item whatsoever now. Originally I had a custom navigation bar.

I'm not too sure what's going on here. Thanks for any help.

```
- (void)customizeAppearance {
    UIImage *NavBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav bar.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavBG forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image: My storyboard]

init View Controller code from .m

```
#import "initViewController.h"
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface initViewController ()

@end

@implementation initViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];

}
```

from .h

```
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"

@interface initViewController : ECSlidingViewController

@end
```

from main.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"


@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController
{
    NSArray *toDoList;
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
} 

@synthesize menuBtn;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

from main.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *menuBtn; // go to MenuViewController.m and synthesize

@end
```

Second view controller.m file

```
    #import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize menuBtn;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Below is the same stuff pasted from MainViewController.m



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;



    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];

    }

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];

    self.menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    menuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(8, 10, 34, 24);
    [menuBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [menuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(revealMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [self.view addSubview:self.menuBtn];
}
```

Here are all the arrays I use

[image: All arrays]

Answer (score -1):

From the image you are showing, it doesn't look like any of the VCs have the starting arrow to its left. If that is the case, go to SB, click on the Nav controller, go to Attributes inspector on the right,scroll down and check the "Is initial View Controller".

Hope this answers it.

Update: Guessing at your code, you are trying to modify an immutable NSArray. Change your declaration to NSMutableArray *toDoList.

Comment: It threw an exception "terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'"

Comment: also you can't see it, but to the far left is an Init View Controller

Comment: Can you show some more code? this looks like it is related obviously to an NSArray. Also, how is the init View controller pushing to the Nav?

Comment: This is an NSarray issue so we would need to see the code related to your NSArray *toDoList. A recommendation: if using SB, you do not need initWithNibName, delete that method from all classes. SB now does the init'ing for you.

Comment: added more code from second view controller. change to NSMutableArray didn't work

Comment: his is an NSarray issue so we would need to see the code related to your NSArray *toDoList

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23931/discussion-between-stangmmx-and-spectravideo328)

Comment: @stangmmx,voting down my answer when I have tried to help because I decided not to go to private chat is unfair. this is the reason you have many downvotes on your questions. I am flagging your question.

Comment: My understanding was that you downvote answers that aren't helpful. My problem still remains so... yeah. It's not like it's a personal attack. I'm grateful for your help regardless of the resolution.